# Before Page Unload show Custom dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When a Page unload, i want a confirm box and it is possible with following code

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (event) {
        return "Chandan From Mandya";
    });
```

But instead of confirmation box i want to show customized dialog box. 
I have read so many blogs, all are saying that we can't override.

But in facebook they are doing it. When in fb status we write something, and without posting, if we try to leave the page. they are show customized dialog box.

How that is possible ???

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery, this is done with `unload` event.

> The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event. Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered. Even a page reload will first create an unload event.

You can use it like this:

`$( window ).unload(function() {` 
  `//Handling the event` 
`});`

The link to jQuery page is: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

As for the custom dialog box, try some of these: 
http://bootboxjs.com/ 
http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3

There are a lot of custom dialogbox solutions out there, just google it.

Comment: i want an customized dialog box on unload event. But you are saying. Both separately.